# how I can get direct access of control placed in User control?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls

I have a label under my user control. Below is the XAML code of my User Control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Class_CalcProject"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Class_WPFCalc_Project.WPF_Calculator.ViewModelCalculator"                 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Class_WPFCalc_Project"                 
             mc:Ignorable="d"  
             d:DesignHeight="315" d:DesignWidth="650"
             Loaded="SetTextBoxFocus"
             KeyUp="KeyBoardHelper">

   <Grid>
      <Label x:Name="lblHello" />
   </Grid>
</User Control>
```

Below is the Code behind file of User Control in VB.NET:

```
Import System.Data
Import System.ComponentModel
Import System.Collections
Import System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class Class_CalcProject
     Public Sub New()
           InitializeComponent()
     End Sub
End Class
```

I have another Class File with Name Testing.vb

```
Import System.Data
Import System.ComponentModel
Import System.Collections
Import System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class Class_Testing

End Class
```

My question is Is there any way to access my Label1 (Control) which is placed inside User Control in Testing Class? Where I can directly Change /set any property of Label1. Something similar like:

```
Label1.IsEnabled = True
```

or

```
UserControl.Current.Windows.OfType(Of Class_CalcProject)().First().Label1.IsEnabled = True
```

In norwal WPF application I can able to access my label control in Testing Class by writing and change / set its property:

```
Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of Class_CalcProject)().First().Label1.IsEnabled = True
```

In windows WPF application the above code is working fine for me. But when I try to convert from Windows to User Control it doesn't work. As I am newbie in WPF and vb.net. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for posting your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DataContext` class for your `UserControl` and bind it's various properties to properties in that `DataContext` class.

It is considered best practice to observe the MVVM pattern and make your `ViewModel` class the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`. Your Testing Class could be that VM it would just need some modifications...

It is also best practice to use Data Binding instead of accessing the control properties in code behind so instead of `Label1.IsEnabled = True` you'd have `<Label x:Name="lblHello" IsEnabled={Binding HelloLabelEnabled}/>` in your XAML and `HelloLabelEnabled` property in your `ViewModel` which implements some form of change notification...

That's how things are supposed to work in WPF... you could, in theory, continue to code all this in your code-behind but that is highly discouraged and will make your life miserable in the long run...

Answer (score 0):

This is what Properties are for. You shouldn't be able to access those controls outside the UserControl directly. But you can.

Any `Control` in .Net has a property called `Controls`, which lists the controls immediately inside the parent. You can get them all with some recursion in an extension method:

```vb
<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(ctrl)
        result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
    Next
    Return result.ToArray().Select(Of T)(Function(arg1) CType(arg1, T)).ToList()
End Function
```

This method returns all children controls from the parent. From here, you would need to get the control you are looking for by name. Usage:

```vb
Dim myLabel = CType(TeradiodeTestPanel1.ChildControls.Where(Function(c) c.Name = "Label1").Single(), Label)
```

The `Single` method will throw an exception if the control isn't found, so Try...Catch accordingly.